# Solarized background colour off in emacs under tmux

Tags: emacs, tmux, solarized

Exhibit I: plain Emacs.

[image: Plain Emacs.]

Exhibit II: Emacs under tmux.

[image: Emacs under tmux.]

The shades of colours are different, and importantly, the background colour differentiation is nil (e.g. look at the top menu).  Anyone run into this?

I'm running tmux as `tmux -2`, `$TERM` in tmux is `screen-256color`, I'm using `color-theme-solarized dark` in Emacs, and Solarized for iTerm2 … a bit baffled!

Comment: Strangely, setting `TERM=xterm-256color` inside tmux seems to fix it (in that the colours look right; I can't say for sure if something will mess up later or not).

Comment: … not totally fix it—it still doesn't discriminate some colours in the same way. Weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same issue in Vim. Using the following in my `~/.tmux.conf` worked for me after creating a new tmux session:

`set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

Comment: Wow, sorry! Forgot about your answer. I ended up settling on `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"`. I'm not sure why, but it seems to have done the trick. Your answer got me there, though!

Comment: tmux overrides the `TERM` value with `screen-256color` where instead you want `xterm-256color` for you emacs. If the tmux config trick doesn't work (it doesn't for me) you can alias emacs to `"TERM=xterm-256color emacs -nw"` in your `.bashrc`. See this bug report for solarized https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized/issues/104.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

`COLORTERM=truecolor emacs -nw`

From: https://emacs.ch/@whhone/110340958779040888

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please note my question is 12 years old at this point, but thanks.