# Vim Solarized dark theme looks weird on iTerm2

Tags: vim, solarized

I just installed the `solarized` colorscheme following instructions on the project's [page](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized).

This is what it looks like now:
 [image]

which is not like those [screenshots](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#screenshots) on the official page.

Any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT**: 
This is the color setup of my iterm2 profile.
[image]

**Problame Solved**
Find the answer in [Solarized background colour off in emacs under tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/401668/solarized-background-colour-off-in-emacs-under-tmux)

Comment: Those screenshot are in MacVim, not in a terminal. Did you install the palette fot iTerm? what is the value of `$TERM`?

Comment: @romainl My `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`

Comment: @romainl I've installed the `solarized dark palette`. The reason may be the `cterm_fg` value of some of these highlight are different from the background color, making it looks like there are lots of holes on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, the first is to add the following line to your `.vimrc` to use a slightly degraded version of the colorscheme:

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
```

Or you can install the the color palette `iterm2-colors-solarized/Solarized Dark.itermcolors` from the [following download](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/files/solarized.zip) off of the author's website.

*Source:* [Solarized Readme](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#installation), "IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS" section.

Comment: Thanks. But I am already using `Solarized Dark` for `iterm2`. I've also tried setting `solarized_termcolors=256`, which seems to disable all syntax highlights.

Comment: Could you possibly post a screenshot of your iTerm2 `Preferences>Profiles>Colors` window? I just downloaded and set it up on my own computer and everything seemed to work as it should.

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot of my color setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue and the following worked for me:

> In iTerm2, in Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal, under "Terminal Emulation" you have "Report Terminal Type:" set to xterm-256color.

Mine was set to just xterm and resulted in the funky coloring. Hope this helps.

edit: via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278267/incorrect-colors-with-vim-in-iterm2-using-solarized

Answer (score 0):

I had found this same problem.  Many people are stuck with 256-term color translation issues.  However, I found that the 'washed out' look remains even when it is configured correctly.

I suspect this is because of the choice of colors.  I respect Ethan's work, but I don't find them high-contrast enough, *even after calibrating my monitor*.  (if someone could show me a more-correct way to think about it, I welcome that)

My solution was to modify the color definition files.  [You can find my modifications here in m fork.](https://github.com/NewAlexandria/solarized/commit/f304f519b1c28606d6f3d9ebe09f9006b20bfb78)

Answer (score 0):

I imported solarized themes into iTerm2. The color looks weird. **But it sometimes works.**
After some tests, I finally find out that it works only if I start iTerm2 with
light solarized theme. Once it works the dark theme works too if I change from
the light one to the dark one!

I get color themes from
https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes

And I find that Solarized Dark Higher Contrast.itermcolors works fine If I start
iterm2 with it.

I think theme files that work may have some key differences. eg. high contract or
something. And the difference only take effect on new started iTerm2.